# php -dom how to use variables as file name while saving to file

Tags: php, dom, save

i want to save an .XML file that i create with php dom, but not with a static name;

```
$dom->save("save.xml");
```

but something that my vary from earlier files;

Solution..

```
$dom->save("{$var1}_{$var2}.xml");
```

Comment: if none of the below work you should at least point out what errors you get and what `$var` contains.

Comment: What exactly does `$var` contain? `"i dont know"`?

Comment: @teutara: This is unrelated to dom. You must provide a valid filename. Consult the technical specification of the filesystem you want to save the file to about validity of filenames, restrictions about filename sizes and all that stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$var = stripslashes($var);
$dom->save("{$var}.xml");
```

Comment: thanks seferov, i tried that and gives an error "failed to open stream: Invalid argument"

Comment: thanks again, but how to use $var with a long string??

Answer (score 2):

Another approach

```
$dom->save($var.'.xml');
```

Comment: thanks Shakti, error "failed to open stream: Invalid argument" ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to have quotes to have the value of the variable. Try this:

```
$dom->save("$var.xml");
```

Comment: thank you Waynn, but this does not work..

Comment: What errors do you get? Can you post more code?

Comment: [domdocument.save]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Comment: I think it's failing at another point in your code, not on the line you're showing.